# изучение js, тонкости, книги, курсы или советы все что угодно

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Недавно присоеденилась к вам(разработчикам) вот, сколько времени мне потребуется чтобы изучить JS? у меня есть такая особенность, если не узнаю что я изучаю то есть суть то не могу переварить информацию, помогите плиз.

Comment: Кто-то и в несколько месяцев уложится, а кто-то вообще никогда не осилит.

Comment: Учу уже 8 лет. Пока еще не выучил :(

Comment: И зачем писать html, css теги, когда об этом в вопросе и речи нет? Основы для JS Вам дадут книги и бесплатные курсы. А все остальное задачи и опыт растущий годами выполненных работающих разработок

Answer (score 1):

Начните с бесплатного курса на htmlacademy
А дальше я советую плясать от задачи. Если будет конкретная задача "реализовать вот это", то можно построить алгоритм реализации и точечно гуглить функции и методы, которые позволят выполнить то или иное действие. Так и набьете руку и получите базу для дальнейшего развития, появится понимание пробелов в знаниях.

Answer (score 1):

Если полностью прочитаешь книгу "Выразительный Javascript" то будет 100% общего понимания языка.